# how to load content of word document in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and JavaScript. I am trying to read the content of a `.doc` file and display it in a textarea.

```
var url = "D:\\way2Jobs\\way2jobz\\WebContent\\pages\\Resumes\\";
var firstName = $("#first").val();
var extn=".doc";
jQuery.ajax({
    url : url+firstName+extn,
    dataType : "doc",
    success : function(data){
        alert(firstName);
        document.getElementById("candResume").innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: Word documents (.doc files) are not in plaintext format, so you need some server-side code to read it's content and to return it in plaintext.

Comment: Why would you show a rich-text document in a textarea?

Answer (score 0):

You just can't (thanks god) make an ajax request to your local filesystem. It's a safety restriction and you can't bypass this.

1 - You have to at least use a webserver like [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)

2 - You never will sucessfuly make a request to D:\

3 - You CAN request a DOC file and process it using javascript. But it's not that easy because DOC file isn't a plain text and javascript was not made for it. Maybe it's easier for you to do it using a server side language such as [PHP](http://php.net/) or [JAVA](http://www.oracle.com/br/technologies/java/overview/index.html) or even [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) if you are familiar with javascript.